# Spring dependency injection got NullPointException when calling its class method

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, nullpointerexception

I have the following Java class that has a field `dao` which is injected by constructor args:

```
public class FeatureFormationFromRaw {

    private MyDAOImpl dao;   //field to be injected from beam.xml

    public FeatureFormationFromRaw(MyDAOImpl dao) {
        //do a fresh clean and save all data, dependency injection by constructor args
        dao.removeAll();          //This is fine.
        dao.saveDataAll();        // This is fine.
    }


    public float calcuFeatures(String caseName) {

        List<JSONObject> rawData = dao.getData(caseName);    //This line throws NullPointException because dao=null here.
                .........
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("bean.xml");
        FeatureFormationFromRaw featureForm = (FeatureFormationFromRaw) context.getBean("featureFormation");

        float value = featureForm.calcuFeatures("000034");

    }

}
```

The bean configuration file `bean.xml` injects the `MyDAOImpl` object to the class via constructor args:

```
    <bean id="featureFormation" class="com.example.FeatureFormationFromRaw">
        <constructor-arg ref="myDaoImpl" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="myDaoImpl" class="com.example.MyDAOImpl">
    </bean>
```

I debugged my application and found that when the constructor `FeatureFormationFromRaw(MyDAOImpl dao)` is executed, `dao` gets the proper value from Spring bean injection. However, when the method `calcuFeatures()` is called, the variable `dao` is null at the first line. Why is that? Why does the variable `dao` disappear and become null after constructor call?

Comment: did you set private MyDAOImpl dao; this in your constructor..i.e this.dao = dao;

Comment: You aren't assigning the variable in your constructor. Also judging from the name you should be programming to interfaces `MyDAO` not implementations `MyDAOImpl`.

Comment: @M.Deinum: Thanks for your suggestion. I could use `MyDAO` rather than the implementing class `MyDAOImpl` in the constructor arg, but then I need to do a cast like `this.dao = (MyDAOImpl) dao`. Is it always a good practice to use interface than implementing class in constructor args? Any guidelines on using interface vs. concrete class in Spring DI constructor args?

Comment: Ideally you should use the interface both for the constructor arg and for the actual variable. This way you get all of the benefit (ability to hide implementation details, ability to easily test) of coding to the interface and of dependency injection.

Comment: @JacobM: Thanks for your comments. This reminds me the fundamentals of OO :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your constructer, having had the dao passed in, you must assign the dao to your private variable.  Otherwise you can't call it anywhere else.

add `this.dao = dao;` to your constructor.

In other words, when you call `dao.removeAll()` within the constructor, that works because it's using the parameter `dao`.  But when you call `dao.getData()` in another method, it fails because it's using the `private MyDAOImpl dao;` which hasn't been initialized. The injection puts it into the constructor, but doesn't put it into the private variable.  You have to do that.

Comment: Thanks. This was what caused the NullPointException. I forgot this line after I get used to DI via setting method.

Answer (score 1):

```
private MyDAOImpl dao;   //field to be injected from beam.xml

    public FeatureFormationFromRaw(MyDAOImpl dao) {
        //do a fresh clean and save all data, dependency injection by constructor args
        dao.removeAll();          //This is fine.
        dao.saveDataAll();        // This is fine.
    }
```

add `this.dao = dao;` inside your constructor ..which has not be assigned so when you are using with other method that time its `null` so you end of with `NPE`